# Can i use or logic in ng-when

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do something like this:

```
<ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1 || matchValue2">...</ANY>
```

To simplify my expression, currently I do that same thing for matchValue1 and matchValue2.

Comment: Use ngIf instead of ngSwitch.

Comment: I'd put a real answer in, but @JBNizet already gave the best answer as a comment.  ng-if can use an OR

Answer (score 1):

[According to angular web site](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) "Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the string "someVal" not against the value of the expression $scope.someVal."

Using `ng-show` would be useful in your case.